# unsigned char inefficiency in C++?

Tags: c++

The following piece of code: `

```
unsigned char agevalue;  
cout<<"what is your age?"<< endl;
cin >> agevalue;
cout<<"your age is:"<< agevalue <<endl;`
```

cuts values greater than 9 and leaves only the first number. 
What can be the reason of this?

Comment: You should always check whether your input was successful after reading, e.g., `if (std::cin >> agevalue) { do_something_with(agevalue); }` The first `std::endl` is definitely unnecessary and use `'\n'` avoids the duplicate flush.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although `unsigned char` is treated like an integer in some contexts, it is primarily intended to represent and individual characters. Thus, your code just reads the first digit. If you want to read a number, you want to use one of the non-`char` integer types, e.g., `int` (this should be your default choice if you need an integer).

Comment: That is, if you enter `123`, `agevalue` is storing the ASCII value that represents the *character* `'1'` (`49`). It then prints out the *character* `'1'`.

Comment: funny, because they said char was just another integer type, but one that can also take letters

Comment: In many ways it is. But from the point of view of parts of the Standard Library, in particular those parts to do with input/output, it is treated differently.

Comment: @Bak1139: the `char` types are certainly all [small] integers and classified as such. However, in contexts where text processing is involved, they are normally treated as characters. The formatted stream operator do treat all three `char` types (`char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`) as characters rather than integers. Likewise, `std::string` has special treatment for `char` types.

Comment: @DietmarKühl This is incredibly annoying when you want to print `uint8_t` and friends. Although that is more of a problem with (lack of) strong `typedef`s I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Its because you are reading a character not an integer.

Comment: but char is also used for integers

Comment: But the `<<` overload for `char`s is written to read a character, even though you can store arbitrary integers in a `char`.

Comment: Please know a character is internally represented by an integer but its type is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pull in numbers, you need to use the correct data type:

```
unsigned short ageValue = 0;
cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
cin >> ageValue;
cout << "Your age is " << agevalue << endl;
```

If you really want to store the age value in a byte-sized integer (instead of a half-word):

```
unsigned char ageValue = 0;
unsigned short inputValue = 0;
cout << "What is your age?" << endl;
cin >> inputValue;
ageValue = static_cast<unsigned char>(inputValue);
cout << "Your age is " << static_cast<unsigned short>(agevalue) << endl;
```